# Getting error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN' when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So, I'm new to MS SQL (have been using oracle for the last 5-7 years) and this should be very a straight forward thing to do, so I reckon I'm missing something very simple.
(I've tried following the examples here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx))

So, I create the following stored procedure to query a table (this is a very simple and pointless procedure but I can't proceed with my more complex procedure until I resolve this problem)

```
create procedure sp_getTransactions
as
select * from MyTransactions;
```

I then try to execute this procedure

```
execute dbo.sp_getTransactions
```

(I've tried without the dbo. and get the same error)

This gives me the very helpful error 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.

Now, maybe I'm crazy but I don't see a begin statement anywhere in my procedure (I've tried adding one to no avail).

Can anyone give me some pointers here?
Thanks

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should note - [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: Are you creating and executing at the same time? If so you need to add `GO` (end of batch command) after creating (or before executing) stored procedure.

Comment: How are you running the `execute` command? Is it perhaps from another stored procedure, or maybe from a multi-statement batch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the problem as it turns out is the client I was using. I was executing the sql scripts using Oracle's SQLDeveloper with the MSSQL jTDS driver. It seems this driver works fine for the most part, but when it comes to running stored procedures there's a bug.
I guess the execute statement isn't parsed properly by the plugin when being set to the server

Answer (score 0):

Check like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getTransactions
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTransactions;
END
```

In `execute dbo.sp__getTransactions` statement, you used 2 `_`, but in CREATE PROCEDURE statement it has only one. Change to `dbo.sp_getTransactions` and try to execute.

Comment: Nope. Same problem
The 2 _ in the execute statement was a typo above.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I think you wrote all the statement and executed as a whole... Just comment the execute command and run the procedure

Comment: Nope. I've created the stored procedure first. Confirmed that it had been added to the procedures area of the schema, then tried running the execute statement.

Comment: Just DROP the procedure and Create it again... Check after that whether it is working or not...

Comment: I've tried that several times. 
Sometimes with the BEGIN and END you suggested adding, sometimes without. 
I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting. 
I've tried creating the procedure and restarting the server before executing. Each time I get the same result

Comment: Did you DROP and Re-create the Stored Procedure?

Comment: Yes, each time I dropped the procedure and re-created it